# Is it possible to uninstall OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice

I installed OpenOffice using the installer downloaded from openoffice.org on Fedora 14.  I went to use it today for the first time and it won't open.  I'm assuming with updates that have been installing that perhaps something got overwritten or something since I didn't install it through yum.  I wasn't sure how to go about uninstalling it now so that I can reinstall it using yum so that it can monitor dependencies for me.  How would I do this?

Comment: Check in `/opt`, and delete everything in there (unless you have other stuff in there). Third party packagers often put their wares there.

Comment: so it won't have installed other things else where or made any other changes?  What about getting items out of the menus?  Its the Gnome desktop and I haven't figured out yet how the menus work exactly... they're not really drag and drop...

Comment: From Superuser: [How to uninstall Open Office from Linux?](http://superuser.com/q/33412/10976)

Comment: Thanks... unfortunately it doesn't appear as though they have an answer either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Installation/How_do_I_uninstall_OpenOffice.org?) (url has been moved):

> OpenOffice.org version 1 (old)
> On Windows, you can use the Add/Remove Programs option in the Control Panel. On Linux, you can use ./setup and choose the Remove option.
>
> OpenOffice.org version 2 & 3 (current)
> If you installed OpenOffice.org through another method (an RPM, or a Debian package), using the appropriate package removal tool is best.

No "Linux" in the text that mentions version 2 & 3, anyway check if the `./setup` file is still there and if there is a "Remove" option.

Another way is, I think inside the archive the packages are really just RPMs. If so you can use [rpm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm) to remove them.